# Refresh Screen to Update ListField with new Data

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am using a ListField Control to display data returned from xml webservice. I want to refresh the ListField or the screen every minute to update the ListField with new records or data.

I tried using the code below but it is not working properly (It is hanging).

```
public MyApp() {
    // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());
        }
    },5000,true);
}
ResponseHandler handler = new ResponseHandler();
ListField listUsers = new ListField(handler.getItem().size());

public MyScreen() {
    setTitle("yQAforum");
    //Fetch the xml from the web service
    String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");
    //Parse returned xml
    SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());
    try {
        saxparser.parse( stream, handler );
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");
    }
    //Return vector sze from the handler class
    listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());
    listUsers.setCallback(this);
    listUsers.setEmptyString("No Users found", 0);
    add(listUsers);
}
```

Comment: What code? Please edit your question and insert the code you want us to look at.

Comment: please show the snippet of code you are having problems with

Comment: I have added the code. Please, I need help.

Comment: does the code hang if you leave only `setTitle("yQAforum");` in `MyScreen()`?

Comment: I don't get you gnat. Did you go through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to fetch data from your webservice on the UI thread.  That's almost always the wrong thing to do.

The UI thread (also known as the *main* thread) is responsible for drawing the UI, and tracking user actions, like touches, or navigation via a trackpad/trackball.  If the UI thread is blocked waiting for a remote web server to respond, it cannot service the UI.

There's a couple changes you should make:

```java
public MyApp() {
    // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyScreen());
        }
    },5000,true);
}
```

should be changed to

```java
public MyApp() {
    // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
    pushScreen(new MyScreen());
}
```

The `MyApp()` constructor will already be called on the UI thread, so there is no need to use `invokeLater()` to perform the `pushScreen()` call on the UI thread.  It already will be called on the UI thread, if run from within the `MyApp` constructor.  Also, the 5000 msec delay isn't really helpful.  This will just delay the startup of your app by 5 seconds, which users will hate.

If you are trying to implement a splash screen, or something similar, when the app starts up, please search stack overflow for "BlackBerry splash screen", and I'm sure you'll find results.

Now, once your `MyScreen` class is created, you should take care **not** to fetch web service results from the UI thread.  The `MyScreen` constructor will be run on the UI thread.  If you want, you can *initiate* a web service request on a background thread, once the screen is shown.  One way to do that is to use `onUiEngineAttached()`:

```java
protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
    if (attached) {
        // TODO: you might want to show some sort of animated
        //  progress UI here, so the user knows you are fetching data

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        // schedule the web service task to run every minute
        timer.schedule(new WebServiceTask(), 0, 60*1000);
    }
}

public MyScreen() {
    setTitle("yQAforum");

    listUsers.setEmptyString("No Users found", 0);
    listUsers.setCallback(this);
    add(listUsers);
}

private class WebServiceTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //Fetch the xml from the web service
        String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");
        //Parse returned xml
        SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());
        try {
           saxparser.parse( stream, handler );
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) {
           response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");
        }
        // now, update the UI back on the UI thread:
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              // TODO: record the currently selected, or focused, row

              //Return vector sze from the handler class
              listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());
              // Note: if you don't see the list content update, you might need to call
              //   listUsers.invalidate();
              // here to force a refresh.  I can't remember if calling setSize() is enough.

              // TODO: set the previously selected, or focused, row
           }
        });
    }
}
```

You'll need to add some error handling, in case the web service doesn't respond, or takes longer than a minute (you wouldn't want to be making a new request, if the last one hadn't finished).

But, this should get you started.

**Note:** once you fix the problem with running network code on the UI thread, you may *still* find that your code doesn't work.  There could be problems fetching the web service data.  You'll have to debug that.  I am only showing you **one** problem with the code posted.  If you still have problems with the web service fetch, post another question (with the UI thread problem fixed).  Thanks.

Comment: Nate, thanks. But after refresh or on refresh it sets focus to the first row in the ListField. I don't want that. I want it to maintain its current focus after refresh so that a user wont even know that there was a refresh.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about that in your question, and the code you posted doesn't do that, either.  If you want to maintain focus, then before refresh (the call to `listUsers.setSize()`), you should do something like call `listUsers.getSelectedIndex()` and then call `listUsers.setSelectedIndex()` after the `setSize()` call.  If that doesn't work, you can try `listUsers.getFocusRect()`.

Comment: Nate, sorry for omitting that. But, which section of the code should I add that?

Comment: as I said, the refresh happens when you call `listUsers.setSize()`.  see my update above.  I put a couple **TODO** comments in about where you'd need to record the focused row, and then re-focus on it, after the refresh.

Comment: listUsers.getSelectedIndex();
             listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());
             listUsers.getSelectedIndex();

Comment: I tried listUsers.getSelectedIndex(); but it didn't work. listUsers.getFocusRect() I have not used it before maybe you could show me. Thanks

Comment: You can't just call `getSelectedIndex()`.  You have to **record** the *result* of that call.  That gives you a row index.  You then pass that row index into a call to `setSelectedIndex(int)`.  Comments aren't really a good place to debug additional problems.  The primary problem you posed in this question was about running a network request on the UI thread.  If you would also like help maintaining row focus during an update, please post a new question, with the exact code you're trying to use.  Thanks.