# Blackberry ListField: Maintaining row focus during an update

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

After using the code below to refresh a ListField containing data returned in an xml web service. But after refresh or on refresh it sets focus to the first row in the ListField. I don't want that. I want it to maintain its current focus after refresh so that a user wont even know that there was a refresh.

```
protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {

    if (attached) {

        // TODO: you might want to show some sort of animated

        //  progress UI here, so the user knows you are fetching data

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        // schedule the web service task to run every minute

        timer.schedule(new WebServiceTask(), 0, 60*1000);

    }

}

public MyScreen() {

    setTitle("yQAforum");

    listUsers.setEmptyString("No Users found", 0);

    listUsers.setCallback(this);

    add(listUsers);

}


private class WebServiceTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {

        //Fetch the xml from the web service

        String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");

        //Parse returned xml

        SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();

        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());

        try {


           saxparser.parse( stream, handler );

        } 

        catch ( Exception e ) {

           response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");

        }

        // now, update the UI back on the UI thread:

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           public void run() {

              //Return vector sze from the handler class

              listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());

              // Note: if you don't see the list content update, you might need to call

              //   listUsers.invalidate();

              // here to force a refresh.  I can't remember if calling setSize() is enough.

           }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Get currently selected row before updating data, and use that index later. Check the documentation, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html. Use `getSelectedIndex()` and `setSelectedIndex(int index)`.

Comment: At which point in the code should I implement that? Cos I have tried it and it didn't work. listUsers.getSelectedIndex();
             listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());
             listUsers.setSelectedIndex(listUsers.getSelectedIndex());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [I suggested in the comments after my answer yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061730/119114), you need to record the currently focused row before you refresh your list, and then set the focused row again, immediately after the update.

So, for example, in the `WebServiceTask`:

```
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          int currentIndex = listUsers.getSelectedIndex();
          int scrollPosition = getMainManager().getVerticalScroll();

          //Return vector sze from the handler class
          listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());

          listUsers.setSelectedIndex(currentIndex);
          getMainManager().setVerticalScroll(scrollPosition);
       }
    });
```

In the code you posted in your comment, you were calling `setSelectedIndex()` with the result of `getSelectedIndex()` **after** you did the refresh, which will never do what you want.

Comment: Nate, thanks it worked! I am so grateful. But I am still having problem maintaining scroll position. How do I go about it?

Comment: I can't see how your `MyScreen` class is defined, but I'm guessing it's a `MainScreen` or something.  Therefore, it will contain a *main manager*, that is normally a `VerticalFieldManager`.  That main manager controls the scroll.  So, just like you record and reset the currently selected list index, you need to record and reset the current vertical scroll position.  See my update to the answer above.  Also, remember to **accept** and/or **upvote** answers that help you.  Thanks.

Comment: Nate, thanks. But do you think this method is the best practice to implement auto-refresh in List Field to update it with data returned in a web service?

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer to your last question, there are other things to think about.  You need to add code to handle network failures.  You should protect the `WebServiceTask`, so that it will not attempt a refresh if the refresh from 1 minute ago is still in progress.  I have no idea what your app does, but for a lot of apps, users will not like their phone automatically making network calls every minute.  That tends to drain the battery.  It would be better if the network calls were only made when necessary.  But, I can't make that recommendation, without understanding the app better.

Comment: The app works like a news feed apps. This means that the List needs to be updated with current news. I really need your recommendation. Thank you.

Comment: Do your readers really need the news updated every minute?  Maybe they do, I don't know.  Would it make sense to have a button that lets them toggle between a mode where the app auto-refreshes every 30/60/90 seconds, or doesn't auto-refresh at all?  Maybe there is a manual refresh button like you see in a browser's URL field?  Anyway, this is a really open-ended question, and requires a full understanding of the app.  I don't have nearly enough information to make that decision for you.  Try breaking your problem down into small chunks, and asking several narrow questions.

Comment: Also, depending on what kind of server infrastructure you have (if any), you may want to look into push notifications, when new content is available.  But, that's just another possibility.  It's impossible for me (or anyone else) to know what's right for you with what you've told us so far.

Comment: Dear Nate. How did bbm contact List function? Don't you think they implemented the List the same way I want mine to work. Cos I noticed the List auto-refreshes.

Comment: I don't know.  I don't work for RIM.  I'm 100% sure, however, that RIM did not write the list to have every BlackBerry device poll the server once a minute, checking for updates to each person's contacts.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I really appreciate everything. I will reconsider and find another option.

Comment: You're welcome.  Again, try breaking the problem into the smallest parts you can.  Stack Overflow is really meant for narrow, programming questions.  If you have a general question about how the user interface would work best, you might try posting it on the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) site.  Or, a general programming question, that asks about the best algorithm for updating a news feed type mobile app, could be posted on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).  Best of luck!

Comment: Hello Mr Nate. I just observed something with the List Field. The data in the List Field duplicate after first refresh!

Comment: If that's the case, then you are doing something wrong in the code that you haven't shown us (in this question, or your last one).  Maybe in your `ListFieldCallback` method implementations.  Please post a new question about this problem, with the full code of your `ListFieldCallback` class (which I think is probably your `MyScreen` class).  It also could be a problem with your `ResponseHandler`, which I also can't see.  Maybe you need to clear out the handler, or create a new handler instance, during each refresh.

Comment: [How to prevent a List Field from showing duplicate data after auto-refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086650/how-to-prevent-a-list-field-from-showing-duplicate-data-after-auto-refresh)

Comment: Dear Nate, I have created it.