# How to prevent a List Field from showing duplicate data after auto-refresh

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I used the code below to refresh a List Field with data returned from an xml web service every minute. But after first refresh, the data duplicates. How do I prevent it from duplicating?

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements ListFieldCallback
{
    ResponseHandler handler = new ResponseHandler();
    ListField listUsers = new ListField(handler.getItem().size());
    Manager mainManager = getMainManager();

    protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
        if (attached) {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            // schedule the web service task to run every minute
            timer.schedule(new WebServiceTask(), 0, 3000);
        }
    }

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle("Uikro");
        listUsers.setEmptyString("No Users found", 0);
        listUsers.setCallback(this);
        add(listUsers);
        handler.getItem().removeAllElements();
    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            //Fetch the xml from the web service
            String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");
            //Parse returned xml
            SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
            ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());
            try {
                saxparser.parse( stream, handler );
            }
            catch ( Exception e ) {
                response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");
            }

            // now, update the UI back on the UI thread:
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Return vector sze from the handler class
                    int currentIndex = listUsers.getSelectedIndex();
                    int scrollPosition = getMainManager().getVerticalScroll();
                    //Return vector sze from the handler class
                    listUsers.setSize(handler.getItem().size());
                    listUsers.setSelectedIndex(currentIndex);
                    getMainManager().setVerticalScroll(scrollPosition);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) {
        String personToDraw = (String) this.get(list, index);
        int drawColor = Color.RED;
        g.setColor(drawColor);
        g.drawText(personToDraw, 0, y, 0, w);
    }

    // get the selected index from the correct Vector
    public Object get(ListField list, int index) {
        return handler.getItem().elementAt(index);
    }

    public void insert(String toInsert, int index) {
        handler.getItem().insertElementAt(toInsert, index);
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField list) {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
        return handler.getItem().indexOf(prefix, start);
    }
}

public class ResponseHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    boolean username=false;
    Vector _vectorUser = new Vector();

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes){
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("U_Username")){
            username = true;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
        if (username){
            _vectorUser.addElement(new String( ch, start, length ));
            username=false;
        }
    }

    Vector getItem(){
        return _vectorUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the problem is in the `ResponseHandler` class.  That class uses a member variable `_vectorUser` to store the data.  The vector is created when the `ResponseHandler` is created, and elements are added when the `characters(char[],int,int)` method is called.

But, `_vectorUser` is **never really cleared out** (it's cleared before it's ever used, but that doesn't prevent this problem).

So, either you should clear out the vector each time you ask the web service for new data:

```
private class WebServiceTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //Fetch the xml from the web service
        String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");
        //Parse returned xml
        SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());
        try {
            // clear out the vector first
            handler.getItem().removeAllElements();
            saxparser.parse( stream, handler );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");
        }
```

or, just create a new `ResponseHandler`, which will also create a new vector:

```
private class WebServiceTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //Fetch the xml from the web service
        String wsReturnString = GlobalV.Fetch_Webservice("myDs");
        //Parse returned xml
        SAXParserImpl saxparser = new SAXParserImpl();
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wsReturnString.getBytes());
        try {
            // create a new handler
            handler = new ResponseHandler();
            saxparser.parse( stream, handler );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            response.setText( "Unable to parse response.");
        }
```

Comment: Dear Nate, it worked. But the screen scrolls on refresh. Assuming focus is on the middle row, when refresh occurs it pushes that row down and make it appear as the last row on that particular screen. Those changes should occur without the user noticing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we already discussed this in your last question.  You have to record the vertical scroll position, and the currently selected row **before** you refresh the UI by calling `setSize()` on your list.  **After** that, you need to *set* those same values for scroll position, and selected row index, in order to keep the screen looking the same.  I did test this in the code I posted yesterday.

Comment: I also can't say what your web service is doing.  I don't know what the format of the data it returns to you is.  If the web service returns you a list of users (or a list of anything), but it doesn't preserve the **order** of that list, then that will cause you problems, and will make it look like the list row order is getting messed up.

Comment: Finally, if the size of your list is actually changing every minute (when you get new web service data), then you may need more complicated logic to preserve the row scroll and focus.  Especially if the list gets *shorter*.  If it shrinks, your recorded `currentIndex` and `scrollPosition` may be past the end of the list.  You'll need to code to protect against that.  Stack Overflow isn't meant to be a source of free labor to write and test the whole program for you.  It's to get you unstuck on problems you have trouble solving.  You still need to use the debugger, and do some testing yourself.

Comment: Guys, If you have power to change web service I would probably not always download all users, but operate more with updates. I think it would minimize data network amount as well will save cpu power to not refresh list completely every time. As well you refresh period is 3 seconds right now. and even with one minute it will drain battery a lot!

Comment: @EugenMartynov, thanks!  I made a similar comment [in the last question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14078434/119114) :)

Comment: Sorry about that Nate. I am very new in java programming. Just started like 2 months ago and I don't have one single book on programming BB apps with Java. I am a .net programmer and I have been on it for like five years and from the day I started till date I don't think I have created one single post on any forum for solutions.

Comment: No need to apologize.  I'm just trying to give advice to help you get the best answers.  Break your problem into separate small little parts. Ask one question.  Get an answer, incorporate it into your code.  If it still doesn't work, collect some `System.out.println()` or debug information, and post it with the new code in a follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I really appreciate. I will do as advised.